# serialize adaboost classifier scikit-learn

Tags: python, serialization, scikit-learn, pickle, adaboost

I'm trying to use scikit-learn AdaBoostClassifier, and i'm trying to serialize the output classifier using cPickle to save it to database or a file, but i got out of memory error, and when i used marshal, it gave me the unmarshable object. So, i'm wondering how i can serialize this learned classifier.

```
def adboost_classify(X,Y):
   bdt = AdaBoostClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10),
                    algorithm="SAMME.R",
                     n_estimators=3000)
   t0 = time()
   bdt.fit(X, Y)
   t1 = time()
   thebytes = cPickle.dumps(bdt)
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is because you attempt to store the whole representation in memory. Try writing it to a file directly instead:

```
with open('adaboostpickled.tmp', 'w') as output:
    cPikle.dump(bdt, output)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually saving the classifier to a file can be done by joblip.dump, but it will save it without any compression to more than three thousand file. if and compression added to save it to one file, it will give memory error also. And the other issue is that this solution will not work to send the classifier to database or throw network.

Comment: @user3155174 I haven't verified it, but shouldn't it work with anything *writeable* (i.e. any stream - also network stream)?